# CakePHP 1.3: Detect ajax request in view

Tags: ajax, cakephp

Before Cake 1.3 I would check for an ajax request with a simple `$ajax->isAjax()`. Now that the `AjaxHelper` has been deprecated, I'm looking for the proper way to check for an ajax request in my views. I can't find anything in the `JsHelper` or `HtmlHelper` methods. This seems like a really simple thing, I hope I'm not missing something obvious!

By the way, I'm aware of the `RequestHandler` component (`$this->RequestHandler->isAjax()` in controller), but again I'm looking for help on how to do the ajax detection in my views.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can you not use the RequestHandler component to set a view variable in the beforeFilter function of app_controller?

Something like this:

```
$this->set('isAjax', $this->RequestHandler->isAjax());
```

This way you can simply check $isAjax in your views.

Comment: Yep, rather straightforward. Works great. Thanks.

Comment: if this is failing for anyone and you happen to be using some kind of custom ajax framework (instead of one from a large javascript library), make sure that your request headers are being properly set:
e.g. req.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
cake php sniffs for this when setting isAjax()

Answer (score 5):

In views check if $this->params['isAjax']